# UILabel text overlapping

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uilabel

I am using 4 UILabels in one view.

```
-(void)setQuestion{
Challenge = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 70, 294, 150)] autorelease];
Challenge.text = challengetext ;
Challenge.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
Challenge.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:Challenge];

Question = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 100 + Challenge.frame.size.height, 294, 150)] autorelease];
Question.text = activeQuestion ;
Question.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
Question.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:Question];

Answer = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 130 + Challenge.frame.size.height + Question.frame.size.height , 294, 150)] autorelease];
Answer.text = [theQuiz objectAtIndex:row+1] ;
Answer.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
Answer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:Answer];

Description = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 160 + Challenge.frame.size.height + Question.frame.size.height + Answer.frame.size.height , 294, 150)] autorelease];
Description.text = [theQuiz objectAtIndex:row+2] ;
Description.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
Description.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:Description];
}
```

There is a one button for next Question.

```
-(IBAction)next{

[scrollview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO]; 
NSInteger endOfQuiz = [theQuiz count];
//[Challenge setHidden:YES];
if((((questionNumber - 1) * 4) + 4) == endOfQuiz)
{
    restartGame = YES;


}else
{
        [self setQuestion];        
}
}
```

When i tap on next button i got the next question from my text file.
But the problem is every time i tap next the text on label overlaps.

What should i do for that??

Thanks..

Comment: Paste code for button click event

Comment: Can you hide the previous label or remove it from the view? Or perhaps provide a screenshot so we can better understand this.

Comment: u have to change all 16 value here CGRectMake(16, 70, 294, 150)

Comment: @Praveen s : makes no change.. still overlapping..

Comment: No paste the code where you are changing the labels,

Comment: @Vijay : it doesnt make change.. :(

Comment: what is the scrollRectToVisible there for ?

Comment: @Matt : To get Scrollview at position at x =0 , y = 0

Comment: Aah ok, i see you are scrolling vertically. just one question, instead of adding the labels then removing and adding more, why not just keep references in your controller, to each of the labels, and when next is touched just set the text to the new text. This way there is no constant alloc and dealloc (when you user removeFromSuperview. you can then dealloc the labels in the controllers dealloc selector ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `removeFromSuperview` your labels before doing `[self setQuestion]`:

```
- (IBAction)next {

    [scrollview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO]; 
    NSInteger endOfQuiz = [theQuiz count];
    //[Challenge setHidden:YES];
    if((((questionNumber - 1) * 4) + 4) == endOfQuiz) {
        restartGame = YES;
    } else {
        [Challenge removeFromSuperview];
        [Question removeFromSuperview];
        [Answer removeFromSuperview];
        [Description removeFromSuperview];
        [self setQuestion];        
    }
}
```